# rcs and graphical diff

Tags: diff, rcs

I have a machine running Ubuntu 6.06. Source files under rcs (no git available).

I need to visually compare older revs of files with the checked out version.
Until now I have moved the file and compared.

```
mv test.c tmptest.c
co -r1.16 test.c
xxdiff test.c tmptest.c
mv tmptest.c test.c
```

I know I can make this in a script, but is there a better way to do this? Without touching test.c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the version to stdout with `-p` and then pipe into xxdiff:

```
co -p1.16 test.c | xxdiff - diff.c
```